# create an alert using css, jquery/javascript arrays or switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing some experimenting. So this may look bad to javascript experts here. But I'm trying to learn.

I have a header div that will show a larger image when the user mouses over each thumbnail image. I used jQuery to create this effect. The header div contains a button. Once the button is clicked, an alert will pop up to tell the user the artist's name of image. The button is wired to an ID of a paragraph. Problem is, my code is not working. I don't want to use "onclick" inline javascript (which is what I am using to call the showArtistname() function). I want unobtrusive javascript like jQuery is. I'm not sure how to do this. I don't know if I should use an array or if I'm even approaching this correctly. Well, it's not correct, because it's not working...

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
$("a:has(img.small)").mouseover(function(){
var bigImage= $(this).attr("href");
$("#heading").attr({src: bigImage});
return false;
});

});
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
function showArtistname(){ 

var a = document.getElementById   ("bluesails", "purplemountains", "bigsky", "nightlights", "fireysunset", "brilliantsunrise").innerHTML;


switch(a) {
case "bluesails":
    alert("Arthur MacKenzie")
    break
case "purplemountains":
    alert("Maggie Laing")
    break

case "bigsky":
    alert("Arthur MacKenzie")
    break

case "nightlights":
    alert("Aria Soriano")
    break

case "fireysunset":
    alert("Felix Buckley")
    break

case "brilliantsunrise":
    alert("Felix Buckley")

}
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container_12" id="_container">

<div class="grid_12" id="12_header" > 

    <div class="hc_left_pic"> <img src="images/01_md.jpg" id="heading" alt="Big Image." />
 <div id="showImage" onclick="showArtistname()"></div>
  </a></div> 
</div>



<div class="clear"></div> 




<div class="grid_4" id="artist_container1">
<a href="images/01_md.jpg"><img src="images/01_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small" alt="Small image Blue Sails" /></a>    
    <p class="text" id="bluesails">Blue Sails</p>
</div>


<div class="grid_4" id="artist_container2">
<a href="images/02_md.jpg"><img src="images/02_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small" alt="Small Image Purple Mountains"/></a>
    <p class="text" id="purplemountains">Purple Mountains</p>
</div>


<div class="grid_4" id="artist_container3">
<a href="images/03_md.jpg"><img src="images/03_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small" alt="Small Image Big Sky"/></a>
    <p class="text" id="bigsky">Big Sky</p>
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>


<div class="grid_4" id="artist_container4">
<a href="images/04_md.jpg"><img src="images/04_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small" alt="Small Image Night Lights" /></a>
    <p class="text" id="nightlights">Night Lights</p>
</div>


 <div class="grid_4" id="artist_container5">
<a href="images/05_md.jpg"><img src="images/05_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small"  alt="Small Product Image Firey Sunset"/></a>
    <p class="text" id="fireysunset">Firey Sunset</p>
</div>


<div class="grid_4" id="artist_container6">
<a href="images/06_md.jpg"><img src="images/06_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small"  alt="Small Product Image Brilliant Sunrise"/></a>
    <p class="text" id="brilliantsunrise">Brilliant Sunrise</p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container_12 .grid_4 {
  width: 274px;
  height: 370px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
 }


#showImage{
margin: -170px 20px 80px 700px;
width: 176px;
height: 48px;  
background:url(../images/showimage.jpg);
position:relative;
z-index:100;
}

 .grid_4 img {
position:relative;
left:100px;
top:20px;
padding:0 0 60px 0;
border:none;

}
.grid_4 p {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

p.text {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:.75em;
color:#000;
line-height:1.25em;
font-weight:bold;
}


#12_header {
display: inline;
background-color:#e5e5e5;
border: 3px solid #bfbfbf;
height:225px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:;
color:#000;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:1.2em;

}


.hc_left_pic {
float:left; 
margin-top:15px;
background-color:#e5e5e5;
border: 3px solid #bfbfbf; 
width:935px;
height:250px;
}
```

I hope I've given enough information to get a solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you try JQUERYUI? its much easier. http://jqueryui.com

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this using jQuery. I created the gallery but I don't know how to make the button on header div to show the artist name in an alert.  Would you show how to do this?

Comment: Can you please port the whole code to somewhere online? I would like to see it working rather than studying the whole code. Try jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ try this

Comment: I don't know how to use jsfiddle. I tried copying and pasting the code in the proper section boxes, then all of the sudden, after I pasted the javascript, the scroll bars disappeared and I couldn't see the HTML or CSS.

Comment: ok, i read the documentation for jsfiddle. i'm building the page now.  I don't understand how to use the jQuery dialog box, but that does look like something I would like to use.  i don't know where to begin.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mick/NvncJ/2/  need to add dummy images since i dont have the real ones yet.  so the images will be skewed a bit.

Comment: I don't know why my button image is not showing on the big image header.

Comment: I don't think you can link to that image from outside sitepoint.com. Loading your image URL gets an immediate redirect to the forum page. Don't worry, you are doing well so far; the jsfiddle is nearly there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a bit to learn in the way of jQuery, but we all did at one point, I see what your trying to do above, and your taking the same approach i would have a few years ago. Well done for giving us some code, it shows your not just looking for someone to do free work. Good job.

See below a jsfiddle of what you want.

NOTE:
Ive removed the links as they are made completely redundant (or at least they were with your return false;).
Also I've commented out all the css.
http://jsfiddle.net/YAaFg/

Have fun,

Cheers
Charlie

Comment: Thanks, Charlie.  I will check your code out.  I tried to add a comment, but I had to wait five minutes, so I kept trying to figure it out and I forgot to come back here!  Yes, I'm trying here's my jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/Mick/NvncJ/5/

Comment: please consider including the relevant parts of your code in your answer. A jsFiddle link is indeed nice, but StackOverflow aims to be as self-contained as possible :)

Comment: I was using an id instead of "name" since it's within a paragraph.  Is there a "name" attribute for paragraphs?  I couldnt' find it googling.  To use 'id', how would I write that?

Comment: The "name" attribute is not relevant for p elements. It's only relevant for form, iframe, meta, object, param elements and fieldset, button, input, keygen, output, select, textarea elelements inside a form element (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/index.html#attributes-1).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your showArtistname function: it always gives the variable a the innerHtml of the element with id "bluesails".

Now there are many possible solutions to achieve your goal. Here is mine:

```
// JQuery part of the code
$(function(){
     $("a:has(img.small)").mouseover(function(){ 
        var bigImage= $(this).attr("href");
         $("#heading").attr({src: bigImage});
         $("#_container").attr({hoveredImage: $(this)});  // Extends your container div with a hoveredImage property, which returns the currently hovered image or undefined 
         return false;
     });
  });

// Plain JavaScript part of the code
oArtistNamesByImageId = {
"bluesails":        "Arthur MacKenzie",
"purplemountains":  "Maggie Laing",
"bigsky":           "Arthur MacKenzie",
"nightlights":      "Aria Soriano",
"fireysunset":      "Felix Buckley",
"brilliantsunrise": "Felix Buckley"
};

function showArtistname(){
    var img = document.getElementById("_container").hoveredImage;
    if(img)alert(oArtistNamesByImageId[img.id]);
}
```

Comment: so both code snippets you wrote will do the same thing? one using jQuery and the other using javascript?  I will test, I just wanted to ask in meantime

Comment: boy do I have alot to learn!  I see you use JSON for the artists names and then create the function.  The jQuery above that code is for the images hover effects

Comment: No, one snippet won't work without the other; I should have been more precise in my post. Just updated.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not exactly what you are after but I have [**made a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NvncJ/8/) which simply clones the image being hovered over into the larger area above.

The `alert()` is taking the *title* attribute of the existing `<img>` element which allows you to keep the artist name as part of the HTML, rather than having to maintain HTML and JavaScript. It also feels more semantically correct, gives your page greater content and is a much simpler solution.

If you need to display a *different* image rather than just a clone, you could add the larger images as hidden elements either inside the top `<div>` and use jQuery [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to un-hide the image.

**Edit:** [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NvncJ/9/) that moves the alert into a click event. This could easily be a click event on the top `<img>` itself its or parent `<div>` if necessary by just changing the selector to `$('#topImage img').click(function() {...});` or `$('#topImage').click(function() {...});`

Comment: Thanks, andyb for your time.  that's a cool way of showing the alert on the mouseove.  I'm trying to have the alert to launch when the user clicks a button. `<div id="showArtist"><!--<img src="images/showArtist.jpg"  alt="Add to Cart"/> --></div>` The image is either in the CSS style or added as an image link.  I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out.  I don't want to do an inline "onclick" event on the div or img.  I'd like it "behind the scenes" as jQuery does.  Any instructions?

Comment: The button is on the larger image

Comment: I've updated the demo, but that was based on your older comment :-) The demo binds the click event to the anchor tag, so not inline. If this needs a bit more work, let me know.